# Swift NSFetchRequest memory leak when assigning fetch result to variable

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-data, memory-leaks

Since the upgrade to Swift 5.2 I have been getting new memory leaks when assigning the fetch results to a local variable in AppDelegate. I using Xcode Instruments (11.2) to view the leaks. Below is the code that used to be memory leak free but no longer is..

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var clipboardFormats: [CoreClipboardFormat]?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        if let context = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
            let fetchy = CoreClipboardFormat.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<CoreClipboardFormat>
            do {
                let res = try context.fetch(fetchy)
                self.clipboardFormats = res // leaks
            } catch {}
        }
    }

   ...

}
```

below you can see the memory leaks... 
[Instruments Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD8Gt.png)